# Button TouchDown is Unknown : monotouch iphone

Tags: iphone, delegates, xamarin.ios

I have a tableview controller in which I show a my custom tablecell.
The table cell contain some controls like image, label, and a button.
What I did overrides the GetCell method and created a new cell of type my custom tablecell,
and seted the values for image, label, and a touchdown event for button.
Now at runtime it shows me the image and label value but on touchdown it fires error.
my code is here

```
cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("IntroCell");                 
mycustomcell cc = new mycustomcell();
if(cell == null)
{ 
    //DebugLog.Write("inside cell cration" );
    NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("IntroCell", nmic, null);
    cell = cc.Cell;
}

cc.DisplayName = contact.DisplayName;
cc.UserPic =  contact.Picture;
cc.ViewDidLoad();

nmic.btnInvitetoMezz.TouchDown += delegate {
    //do something
};
```

I debuged the code, it says that "UnKnown Member : Touchdown".

Any ideas?

Comment: oh my bad, this is typo, it is actually NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("IntroCell", cc, null);

Comment: I meant more so for the `nmic.btnInvitetoMezz` is nmic a reference to another view?

Comment: Very simple, the "nmic.btnIniviteToMezz" is not properly typed, so the compiler does not know that this is a button.

As other posters have said, not clear what "nmic" is

Comment: @ miguel, no actually it is cc.btnInvitetoMezz.TouchDown